# Reverse Byte Array when converting an animated gif to a Unity Texture2D Array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I am currently trying to load animated gifs into a Unity application (during runtime), but I have run into a bit of a snag:

I am using System.Drawing to load a byte array from each gif-frame and then use Unity's LoadRawTextureData function to create the Texture. The problem I have now is that the order of the bytes in the array are not what Unity expects (even though I specify the Format as ARGB32 for both). Apparently, Unity either expects ABGR and System.Drawing gives me RGBA, or vice versa. Also, the image is flipped vertically (but that can be easily remedied).

This is my current code, which works, but I have to reverse the array which increases the time it takes by a factor of 10-20. It is still at least twice as fast as copying each pixel separately, but I would prefer if I could get closer to the performance I get without reversing.

```
GraphicsUnit graphicsUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
RectangleF rect1 = gifImage.GetBounds(ref graphicsUnit);
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle((int)rect1.X, (int)rect1.Y, (int)rect1.Width, (int)rect1.Height);
byte[] rgbValues = new byte[rect2.Width * rect2.Height * 4];

for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
    gifImage.SelectActiveFrame(dimension, i);
    Bitmap frame = new Bitmap(gifImage.Width, gifImage.Height);
    System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(frame).DrawImage(gifImage, Point.Empty);
    frame.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);

    Texture2D frameTexture = new Texture2D(frame.Width, frame.Height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);

    BitmapData data = frame.LockBits(rect2, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, rgbValues, 0, rgbValues.Length);
    frame.UnlockBits(data);

    frameTexture.LoadRawTextureData(rgbValues.Reverse().ToArray());
    frameTexture.Apply();
    gifFrames[i] = frameTexture;
}
```

Is there something else I could try to get the bytes in the 'correct' order?

Comment: The only thing I can tell you is "Don't use anything from System.Drawing in Unity." You have to re-write your code and remove anything about System.Drawing in it.

Comment: Care to elaborate? It works both in editor and build.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the `.Reverse()` if you construct your Texture2D using `TextureFormat.BGRA32`. however, this doesn't really address why its necessary